# Convert Time - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 05:00 AM or 5:00 AM or 00:05:00 AM or 00:5:00 AM or 5 AM (hours....but can also have minutes or seco

I want to convert this to HH:MM:SS The above example is in Hours but it could be in minutes or seconds...

Now, I don't know if this is possible as let's say 05:00 AM could be 5 hours or 5 minutes.
Has anyone came across such situation before? If so, how did you go about dealing with this?

I suppose we can use LEN function to check if it's HOURS or minutes so if 05:00 AM or 5:00 AM, it's minutes if it's 05:00:00 AM or 5:00:00 AM, it's hours.

Or we can check for the # of ":" occurrences and decide if it's hours or minutes or seconds and convert based on that...

Anyone has a better solution?

Thank you

Comment: The best solution is to use a datetime data type

Comment: Do you want to convert a [small]datetime[2] value to a VARCHAR ? Example: `05:06:00` -> `5 hours 6 minutes`

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlean, I don't want that but how can one go about doing it if he/she desires? :)

Comment: @user1569220: So, do you have a desire ? Or he/she ? :-)

Comment: Desire, I do! (I don't want that = I am not looking for that particular format for this task). Also "he/she" could be reworded to "one"? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cast as date
2. Convert to string using format

Below is example of all combinations entered above. Every one returns 05:00:00

```
select convert(varchar(15), cast('05:00 AM' as datetime), 108)
  , convert(varchar(15), cast('5:00 AM' as datetime), 108)
  , convert(varchar(15), cast('00:05:00 AM' as datetime), 108)
  , convert(varchar(15), cast('00:5:00 AM' as datetime), 108)
  , convert(varchar(15), cast('5 AM' as datetime), 108)
```

Comment: Thanks...that seems to work just fine. :) Now, I just have to implement this in SSIS somehow using SSIS datatypes. :)